# Pygame level system causing list indexing errors

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pygame

I have created a pygame, the object of the game is to avoid the balls moving around the screen (random)

```
ballpic = pygame.image.load('ball.png').convert_alpha()
```

I have a level function:

```
def levels(score):
 global enemies
 global velocity
 enemies = enemies
 velocity = velocity

#level one 
if score >= 500:
  enemies = 6
  velocity = 2

#level two
if score >= 1000:
  enemies = 6
  velocity = 2
  #....And so on
```

Game with indentation: ///Expired/

if I try to do that I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\MO\Desktop\Twerk\twerk-bck.py", line 252, in <module>
  game()
File "C:\Users\MO\Desktop\Twerk\twerk-bck.py", line 199, in game
 positionx[i]=positionx[i]+positionxmove[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand I need to append new values to the lists to expand them by 3 more entries. what I'm trying to achieve is to add more balls to the screen score hits certain figure. But I don't have any idea how I can do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Use objects for each ball, that way you don't need to keep lots of lists with the same indices, which is fragile and hard to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `positionx` and friends at line 134 before the main loop at 147.  Then you call `levels(score)` inside the loop, which updates the `enemies` count but doesn't actually allocate more space in `positionx` for the extra enemies.  `levels()` should be responsible for resizing the arrays when it increases the enemy count.

As **Lattyware** commented, using objects for each enemy would be a *much* better design.  Generally if you're keeping any kind of parallel arrays like `positionx` and `positiony`, you should replace them with an array of objects.  Then all your different loops over `range(enemies)` would be replaced by one big loop like:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.update(globalGameState)
```

where `globalGameState` is one or more variables keeping track of stuff like the mouse position that *is the same for all enemies*.